# Enabling IIS to host two websites on the 443 using SSL brakes ActiveSync

Tags: iis, ssl, activesync

I have an SBS 2003 machine to configure.

I am required to host both webmail.company.com:443 & intranet.company.com:443 on the same IIS server using the one IP address and of course the same port (443).

I am able to configure IIS to do this using host headers and updating the metabase using adsutil.vbs, but when I do, ActiveSync stops pushing emails and starts throwing this application error:

Event Type: Error 
Event Source:   Server ActiveSync 
Event Category: None 
Event ID:   3005 
Date:
Time:
User:       domain\user
Computer:   domain
Description:
Unexpected Exchange mailbox Server error: Server: [domain.local] User: [user@domain.com] HTTP status code: [400]. Verify that the Exchange mailbox Server is working correctly.

Notably being an SBS box its both a frontend and backend server so many of the tips around regarding requiring SSL access do not apply.

Any help would be most greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
In reading this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324287 I have noticed it may be because I shouldn't put host headers on the default website where my exchange virtual folders live.  Any confirmation would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is fine, just leave out host headers on the default website.  It will receive traffic still and host headers on the other sites still redirect traffic to them.

Host headers on default website breaks Exchange Active Sync.

Comment: Yep - one site needs a "non" host header in order for the others to fall through to it. So either no host header, or include everything that the ActiveSync client is going to use.